# Custom button drawable state_pressed and state_checked not working on CheckBox or RadioButton - Android

Tags: java, android, checkbox, drawable, android-custom-view

I am setting custom drawable to the checkbox button,
But only `android:state_checked="true"` and `android:state_checked="false"` seem to work.
Other states aren't working.

I am unable to set a custom drawable on pressed state.

**This is the selector I am using:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/radio_btn_selected" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/radio_btn_normal" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/radio_btn_pressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/radio_btn_pressed" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/radio_btn_normal"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

**This is how I am setting it to radio button:**

```
radioButton.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.radio_btn_selectors);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`android:state_pressed="true"` and `android:state_focused="true"` are not working because of the ordering in which you declared various states. Whenever you declare a drawable like this, system will goes from top to bottom and if a state is matched, it doesn't look for the other ones and applies the changes based on the very first selection. I think here `android:state_checked="false"` condition might be executing instead of `android:state_pressed="true"` and `android:state_focused="true"`. So move `android:state_checked="false"` to the bottom and then try.